# Excel to CSV converter

Tags: python, beginner, excel, csv

To check out the cssv module i wrote a small programm which takes all xlsx files in a folder and converts them into csv files.

Let me know what you would improve on this program.

**xlsx_tp_csv**

```
"""
All xlsx files in the folder of the script get converted into csv files
(One for each sheet).
The names are created as excel filename + sheet name.
"""

import csv
import os
from pathlib import Path
import openpyxl

def make_csv_filename(filename_excel: str, sheet_name: str) -> str:
    """
    Make a filename out of the filename of the excel file and
    the corresponding sheet
    """
    return Path(filename_excel).resolve().stem  + '_' + sheet_name + '.csv'

def xlsx_to_csv():
    """Main loop"""
    target_folder: str = 'csv'
    os.makedirs(target_folder, exist_ok=True)

    for filename in os.listdir('.'):
        if not filename.endswith('.xlsx'):
            continue

        workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)

        for sheet_name in workbook.sheetnames:
            sheet = workbook[sheet_name]
            csv_filename = make_csv_filename(filename, sheet_name)
            csv_path: Path = Path(target_folder, csv_filename)

            with open(csv_path, 'w', newline='') as csv_file:
                csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)

                for row_number in range(1, sheet.max_row + 1):
                    row_data = []
                    for column_number in range(1, sheet.max_column + 1):
                        cell_data = sheet.cell(
                            column=column_number, row=row_number).value
                        row_data.append(cell_data)

                    csv_writer.writerow(row_data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    xlsx_to_csv()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good job with the type annotations! Here are a few things you could simplify/improve:

- instead of `listdir` and an extra file extension check, you could use [`glob.iglob()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.iglob):

  ```
  for filename in glob.iglob('./**/*.xlsx'):
  ```
- to improve excel file read performance and memory consumption, you could use [`read_only=True` mode](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/optimized.html#read-only-mode)
- instead of iterating over `sheetnames` and getting a sheet by name, you could [iterate over available worksheets directly](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.workbook.workbook.html#openpyxl.workbook.workbook.Workbook.worksheets):

  ```
  for sheet in workbook.worksheets:
  ```
- [`iter_rows()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31237077/771848) should improve the way you read the sheet cells

---

As a side note and as an idea for an alternative solution: what if you transition the data through a `pandas.DataFrame`, `pandas` has [`.read_excel()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) and [`.to_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) methods.

Comment: Instead of `glob.iglob`, there is also [`pathlib.Path.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob), since OP is already using `Path`.